# Why did Glinda say she was the Good Witch of the North in The Wizard of Oz (1939)

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz, oz-the-great-and-powerful

In *Oz* (2013), Glinda tells Oz she is the Good Witch of the *South*.  Yet in *The Wizard of Oz* (1939), she tells Dorothy she is Glinda the Good Witch of the *North*.  According to [this question](http://In%20**Oz**%20(2013),%20Glinda%20tells%20Oz%20she%20is%20the%20Good%20Witch%20of%20the%20*South*.%20%20Yet%20in%20**The%20Wizard%20of%20Oz**%20(1939%20or%201936%20from%20memory),%20she%20tells%20Dorothy%20she%20is%20Glinda%20the%20Good%20Witch%20of%20the%20*North*.%20%20When%20and%20why%20does%20this%20change%20in%20her%20'jurisdiction'%20occur?%20%20I'm%20looking%20for%20an%20in-universe%20explanation%20if%20it%20exists,%20otherwsie%20an%20out-of-universe%20explanation%20will%20also%20suffice.), it seems that Glinda is indeed the Good Witch of the South according to other sources.  What I'm trying to understand is why Glinda said she was the Good Witch of the North in one film, but she said she was the Good Witch of the South in the other!

Comment: In the book *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz* (1900) she is the Good Witch of the South.  So maybe the question is why that was changed for the movie in 1939...

Comment: At the beginning of the original 1901 novel, Dorothy is met by the witch of the North, who is never named. Later, at the end of the novel, Dorothy travels to the south to see Glinda, the witch of the South, who sends her home.  In the 1939 MGM film, these two witches are combined into a single character.  The third part of the book, with the journey to the south, is omitted, and Glinda appears suddenly ion the Emerald City.